# Tools to paint arrows on screen etc. are not awailable in Flameshot

Tags: 22.04

I have installed Flameshot 11.0.0.

When I selct "Take screenshot", a screenshot of the whole screen is taken.

Then there appears an invitation screen to take another screenshot. And it contains  an "Options" button.

I press it, ant it contains "Grab the area". I select it. I'm allowed to grab the area. But the screenshot is again taken immediately.

But I want to use those tools like arrows, rectangles etc. The usage of them seems to be switched off by default. I can't find where to switch it on. Could you help m?

Comment: Right-click on Flameshot icon and select **Configuration**.

Comment: I have scrutinised Configuration. To the best of my ability I can't find what to switch on.

Comment: After **Take Screenshot** is selected, the screen will be dimmed, the mouse cursor will become a `+` and you will be able to select a screen area. At that state, tools will be displayed around the selected frame. My version is 12 under Ubuntu 22.10, however the usage should be the same.

Comment: On another computer I use Flameshot as you described. But the newly installed one takes screenshots at once.

Comment: I have the same problem. If I start Flamesot, the entire screen is immediately recorded.
Problem exists with linux: 6.5.0-21-generic

It works on linux: 5.19.0-45-generic